# how to do round half even in javascript unlimited digits after point?

Tags: javascript, rounding

I want to have 26.955 rounded to 26.96

I mean if I have numbers 0-4 I want to round them down
and if they are 5-9 I want to round them up

I considered `parseFloat(number).toFixed(2)` however it returns me 26.95, I need 26.96
I used `Math.round` but this doesn't work either, I saw `Math.round10` but it told me this function doesn't exist so I don't know how to solve my problem.

UPDATE: I don't have always 3 digits after point I have more than that I would have 26.956736489

your mentioned duplicate talks about .fixed(2) I am saying it is not working for half even **it is not a duplicate**

Comment: Math.round should be work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try

```
Math.round(29.955*100)/100; //29.96
```

Or cool functional approach

```
function round(n) {
   n = Math.pow(10,n);
   return function(num) {
       return Math.round(num*n)/n;
   }
}

var round2 = round(2);
var num = 29.9555;
console.log(round2(num));
```

Comment: its not doing it for 17.955 i am just so surprised :O why?! but it is doing it for 29.9555

Comment: This is wrong. `Math.round()` doesn't do half even rounding but instead always rounds up on a tie so it has a bias.

Comment: This will not round half even https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Answer (score -2):

use this:

```
var num=26.955
Math.round(num* 100) / 100;
```

Comment: this is my own question what are you talking about

Comment: @Nick Didn't you notice that I posted it under *answer* and link was also to the *answer*?

Comment: yes I did but they answered only in 2 minutes it doesn't mean he cheated on someone else I don't know why stackoverflow became somewhere which I am not comfortable anymore