# Regular expression for converting 0.085 to 0.08

Tags: javascript

I am having regular expression using following code

```
var data = 0.085;
var output = "$"+data.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
console.log(output);
```

The problem is that it does not round off value `0.085` to `0.08`. I am allowed to use this regular expression.

Comment: So... what do you get? 0.09? That's the correct value. Why are you manipulating numbers with regex anyway?

Comment: 0.085 rounded off is 0.9?

Comment: `(data-0.05).toFixed(2)` and no regex rubbish?

Comment: when range is 0 to 4 the value gets converted to lower value if value is greater than 6 to 10 then it get convert to upper value which is correct but here whan there is mid value 5 after any digit it it should get converted to lower value i.e 0.085 to 0.08

Comment: Then why didn't you search for that? Do your research, this took me ten seconds to find: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26806234/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var data = 0.085;
var output = Math.floor(data * 100) / 100;
console.log(output)
```